# Codefights: Given an integer n, return the largest number that contains exactly n digits

Tags: javascript

So I have to find the largest number that contains n digits. For example, if n=2, then the largestNumber = 99. This was my answer.

```
function largestNumber(n) {
    var num = [];
    n = num.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        num[i] = "9";
    };
    var large = +(num.join(''));
    return large;
}
```

Unfortunately, it returned "0". When I tried to console.log the array.

```
function largestNumber(n) {
    var num = [];
    n = num.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        num[i] = "9";
    };
    return num;
}

console.log(largestNumber(2));
```

I got an empty array instead of ["9", "9"]. Why is my array not forming?

Comment: Remove `n = num.length;`. That line is pointless and discards the parameter you passed to the function by resetting it to `0`.

Comment: Simpler method: `function largestNumber(n) { return Math.pow(10, n) - 1; }`

Comment: Of course, `99` is not the largest number that contains exactly two digits.

Comment: @georg What do you mean? `0xFF`? `9e9`?

Comment: @Bergi: yep, the assignment is pretty sloppy formulated.

Comment: @Amit: what does `largestNumber(123456789)` return?

Comment: @georg - There's a limit to the input/output size regardless of method used. Unless range is explicitly specified, I see no problem assuming "useful range" the way I did. More so, the question is about "*largest number*", and your implied issue arises regardless of implementation as a 1e9 digit **number** probably won't work anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use (10^n)-1 ?

Math.pow(10,n)-1

Comment: Is this an answer? (To what question??) Is this a comment??

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting `n` to 0 by assigning it with `n = num.length;` right after defining `num` as an empty array. Just drop this line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using n as the power of 10 and subtracting 1 from the result gives you the correct answer for any integer value of n.

```
def largestNumber(n):
    large = (10 ** n) -1
    print(large)
largestNumber(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
function largestNumber(n) {
let number = "9";
for(let i=1;i<n;i++){
    number += "9";
}
return parseInt(number);
}
```